# Split dataset by grouping variable to create multiple bar plots at once

Tags: r, list, dataframe, bar-chart, split

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

> time, precip, grp
>
> 2005-09-30 11:45:00,1.1,1
>
> 2005-09-30 23:45:00,1.5,1
>
> 2005-10-01 23:45:00,0.2,2
>
> 2005-10-02 11:45:00,0.3,2
>
> 2005-10-02 23:45:00,1.7,2
>
> 2005-10-03 11:45:00,0.8,2
>
> 2005-10-04 23:45:00,1.4,4

I want to make separate data frames for each group (grp, there are a total of 65 groups in my full dataset) and produce a bar graph for each group.

So far, I've made a list:

```
X <- split(df, df$grp)

str(X)

Y <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(x) as.data.frame(X[[x]])[, 1:2]) 

lapply(seq_along(Y), function(x) {assign(grp[x], Y[[x]], envir=.GlobalEnv)})
```

which produces this:

```
>Y

>[[1]]

                 time precip

3 2005-10-01 11:45:00      0

8 2005-10-03 23:45:00      0

9 2005-10-04 11:45:00      0




[[2]]
                    
               time   precip

1 2005-09-30 11:45:00 1.1

2 2005-09-30 23:45:00 1.5


...
```

Is there a way to now plot each of these so that I have a different bar graph for each group, with time on the x-axis and precip on the y-axis? Ideally, the bar graphs would all be on the same page or part of the same output.

Also, is there a way to export each of these as separate data frames?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lattice` is made for this sort of thing.

Using RoyalTS's data `df`:

```
library(lattice)
barchart(time~precip|grp, data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much simpler using ggplot's facet functions:

```
df_string <- 'time, precip, grp
2005-09-30 11:45:00,1.1,1
2005-09-30 23:45:00,1.5,1
2005-10-01 23:45:00,0.2,2
2005-10-02 11:45:00,0.3,2
2005-10-02 23:45:00,1.7,2
2005-10-03 11:45:00,0.8,2
2005-10-04 23:45:00,1.4,4'

con <- textConnection(df_string)
df <- read.csv(con)

# optional if the time isn't actually in a format R understands yet
library(lubridate)
df$time <- ymd_hms(df$time)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df,(aes(time,precip)))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p <- p + facet_wrap(~ grp)
p
```

Comment: Upon reading your question again, did you want a separate graph for each group or all groups in the same graph and merely distinguished (colored?) in some way?